# How to set token details to another page in Angular 2

Tags: angular

In my Angular2 app I can successfully login using a jwt. Once I log in I'm navigating to a profile page. I need to display the first and last name of the logged in user on the profile page. Since I'm new to Angular I need some help.

Here is my `login.component.ts`:

```
import {Response} from '@angular/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiServiceProvider } from '../services/api.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Router,Routes,ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  public user: any = {};

  constructor(private api: ApiServiceProvider,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public onFormSubmit({ value, valid}: { value: any, valid: boolean }) {
    this.user = value;
    this.api.post("/account/login", value, false)
    .subscribe((data) => {
      alert("login success "+ data.token);
      localStorage.setItem("token", data.token);
      this.router.navigate(['profile']);
    }, (err) => {
      alert("login failed "+ err);
    })
  }

}
```

What should I add in my `profile.component.ts` and `profile.component.html` to accomplish this?

Comment: use the same local storage

Comment: If you have first name and last name as claims in your token. Then you need to decrypt jwt token to get first name and last name from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `first_name` and `last_name` are returned in the token. You can get the details 
from the token and show it in html like this:

profile.component.html

```
<div> First Name: {{accountDetails.first_name}}</div>
<div> Last Name: {{accountDetails.last_name}}</div>
```

profile.component.ts

```
import { JwtHelper } from 'angular2-jwt';
// other things omitted for brevity 

export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
    private jwtHelper: JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();
    public accountDetails: any = {}

    ngOnInit() {

        try {
            const access_token = localStorage.getItem("token");
            this.accountDetails = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(access_token).identity;
            // Verfiy that the names of keys are actually first_name and last_name
            // In case they are different change in html
            console.log("token", this.accountDetails);
        } catch (err) {
            // Access token is not proper, maybe it was tampered with
            // implement logic for logging out user
        }
    }
}
```

Usually things like name would be needed across the whole application so it is a good idea to implement the decode token logic in a service and store it in a private variable in a service with a getter, so you don't have to decode it in every component.

Comment: In the console it shows token undefined.why is that ? In my local storage it shows the token.

Comment: Try changing `this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(access_token).identity` to `this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(access_token)`